How to add projects in the git changes
I have a solution (VS) .net v7, blazor with 4 projects. 2 (repositories) are lost in the git changes tab. How can I bring them back? In the Solution Explorer, I see them all.
The repo's comes from DevOps.



I solve this problem by deleting the 2 projects from computer.
And then I clone the 2 projects from DevOps.
The 2 projects appears again in the Git Changes-tab.

